# Django keeps making old db schema

Tags: django, model

I have deleted one column from my model. Then I deleted database, migration files, venv direcotry, and *pycache*. But after executing makemigrations the old db schema is generating ( it still contains this column). What is the problem. How django knows about this column. It's no longer present in data model.

Comment: Does that model inherit from an abstract model that has the column?

Comment: @Melvyn it only inherits from models.Model. Im talking about UserRaport model. Problematic column is "id". Here is models file 
https://gitlab.com/AdamPWr/asystent-pacjenta/-/blob/master/backend/aystent_backend/webApp/models.py

Comment: Ah yes, that's the other possiblity.

Answer (score 1):

Django automatically creates a primary key column if you don't define one in your model. It is [explained here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> By default, Django gives each model the following field:
>
> `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`
>
> This is an auto-incrementing primary key.
>
> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, specify primary_key=True on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column.
>
> Each model requires exactly one field to have primary_key=True (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

Since you happened to declare it explicitly with the same defaults, you won't notice any difference.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to run `python manage.py migrate` after `makemigrations` to commit the changes to the database, then everything should be fine

Comment: Not according to his description.

Comment: Its the only thing that makes sense though, in his description he did not say anything about migrating the database

Comment: He deleted the database, old migrations, even venv, deleted a column from model, but `makemigrations` created again a schema with that column. That's how I read the question and in that case, deleting the database or migrating does not have any impact on the issue.

Comment: but he didnt say anything about migrating the database

Comment: He doesn't have to. It's irrelevant. But if you extend AbstractUser and reimplement for example `email` field with 60 chars, then delete the `email` field, it will still show up, just with different max_length.

Comment: Ya. I have made makemigration to generate new db schema. And old column is still there. I have no idea how django even know about it. It have to remember it somehow

Comment: Did you run "python manage.py migrate" after that?